# Spring integration: use Splitter and Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm reading files line by line using FileSplitter, and then  filter some of the corrupted lines - as to discard some lines - in order to do webservices calls for each line.

What I need to do in addition to this is to get the file moved to completed files directory.

**Update:** Just to be more clear, the successful/good lines after filtering will need to be aggregated in a file to be written to the completed directory and the corrupted/filtered lines will be written to another one.

Mentioning the above, I was not clear about the following points:

- Will I need some kind of correlation between the messages/lines as to
  provide it manually or Spring Integration will do it for me?
- If some lines are discarded due to the filtering, what is the right
  strategy to use with the aggregator?
- How can I make use of file markers as to identify when the file is
  completed to move to the completed directory?

The scenario simply looks like:

```
FileSplitter -> line Filter -> Outbound Gateway (webservices) -> Aggregator
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] which reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileSplitter` can be configured to emit `FileSplitter.FileMarker` as the first message with the `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.START` and in the end with the `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END` respectively.

You can add a router (`PayloadTypeRouter` should be enough) after splitter to handle `FileSplitter.FileMarker` in a different flow. And if it is a `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END` you just perform a desired logic *to move to the completed directory*.

I don't think that you need an aggregator for this scenario.

Anyway the `FileSplitter` can be configured with the `setApplySequence(true)` to be able to correlate a group downstream in the aggregator. But you still won't be able to know the size of the group to release it in time. The `FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END` still can help here, although I don't see the reason in that for your task.

There is some info on the matter in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-splitter).

Comment: See the [`file-split-ftp` sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp)  for an example of using markers to determine the end of processing (in that case it sends 3 parts of the file to different FTP servers).

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers, but i still have a concern regarding having the FileMarkers routed to the aggregator through a different flow than the other lines, because of the delays in the Outbound Gateway (webservices) requests/responses.

will the 'END' FileMarker arrive to the aggregator before the last line coming back from the Outbound Gateway?

Comment: That's fine too. The `FileMarker.END` will have an information how much line it has read. So, you will need to implement a smart `ReleaseStrategy` to check for the `FileMarker.END` presence in the group and compare that `lineCount` with the size of the group. Therefore even if `FileMarker.END`  will arrive to the aggregator much earlier then other processed lines, you still won't come out from the aggregator because you are waiting for all the lines.

Comment: I think what you need here should be implemented with the https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4116